# Primefaces multiple selection lists

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using the Primefaces dataTable multiple selection with checkboxes to select multiple rows from the datatable. The problem is that i want to have two columns of checkboxes which store the selected rows in two seperated lists.

In my datatable i can only specify one list with the selection attribute to store the selection in:

```
 <p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" style="margin-bottom:0">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
```

Is there a way to specify more than one List in the dataTable selection attribute like that:

```
selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars1, dtSelectionView.selectedCars2}"
```

And after that, having two selection-columns defined in the dataTable:

```
<p:column id="checkboxes1" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
<p:column id="checkboxes2" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
```

Comment: Primefaces as of now does not have such feature which you are looking for but this problem of yours could be solved by another workaround.

Comment: Workaround will be like you have to add two boolean variables in the List class and based on that you can identify which row is selected for what. So by this you will have a single row selection checkbox and two more boolean checkbox  in the datatable. I hope this solves your problem.